# Non-static ... static what?

Tags: mysql, java

I know about the concept static and non static as I found the explanation on here. But I am not sure if I understand it. My code generates the following error: non-static method getWerknemers() cannot be referenced from a static context.

If I make the method `getWerknemers()` static, all the variables get similar errors instead. What am I doing wrong?

```
package huiswerk;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Opdracht_1 {

    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;
    String naam;
    String functie;
    String woonplaats;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getWerknemers();
    }

    public void getWerknemers() {
        DatabaseConnectie con = new DatabaseConnectie();
        try {

            String query = "SELECT * FROM werknemer";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Gegevens uit de database: ");
            while(rs.next()) {
                naam = rs.getString("naam");
                functie = rs.getString("functie");
                woonplaats = rs.getString("woonplaats");
                System.out.println("Naam: " + naam + "\nFunctie: " + functie + "\nWoonplaats: " + woonplaats + "\n");
            }

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `main` method is `static`, so it can't directly call `getWerknemers`, because it's not `static` and `main` doesn't have an instance of your `Opdracht_1` object.  If you make `getWerknemers` static, then it doesn't have access to your non-static class variables.

The easiest solution is to create an object to call its non-static method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Opdracht_1 op = new Opdracht_1();
    op.getWerknemers();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getWerknemers();
}
```

Here you're calling the non-static method getWerknemers() from the static Main method. Change that to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Opdracht_1().getWerknemers();
}
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to call a class method from a static method. You first need to make an object of type Opdracht_1, and then call the method from that object. Try the following for your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Opdracht_1 o = new Opdracht_1();
    o.getWerknemers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if you want to call a method (lets say `bar()`) from a static method (like `main()`), it has to be static:

```
public class Example {
    public static void foo() {
         System.out.println("I'm foo!");
    }
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("I'm bar");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         foo(); // Will run with no problem
         bar(); // Won't run, because it is not a static method
    }
}
```

If you want to call `bar()`, you have to create an object and call the object non-static method:

```
public class Example {
    public static void foo() {
         System.out.println("I'm foo!");
    }
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("I'm bar");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         foo(); // Will run with no problem
         Example e = new Example();
         e.bar(); // Should run now
    }
}
```